# XML to XML trasformation using Xslt

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

I'm newly for the xslt and Xpath.i need to transform xml to another xml file using xslt. so i need to get `Name` element.i'm using xpath.but getting below error when i run my xslt. anything i missing or went wrong ?

> Error: net.sf.saxon.s9api.SaxonApiException: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 22; columnNumber: 22; The prefix "arr" for element "arr:string" is not bound.

Input file.XML

```
<Accounts>
<Account>
    <Name></Name>
</Account>
<Accounts>
```

need to get `<Name>` element

my xpath is (this is not fully xslt file. included only get name element code)

```
         <arr:string>
            <xsl:value-of select="/Accounts/Account"></xsl:value-of>
         </arr:string>
```

output is -:

```
            <qqq:Fields>
               <arr:string>Name</arr:string>
               <arr:string>XXX</arr:string>
               <arr:string>xxxxx</arr:string>
               <arr:string>xxxxx</arr:string>
            </qqq:Fields>
```

Comment: Your question is not clear, but the error message is: you cannot use `<arr:string>` without binding the `arr:` prefix to a namespace first. Do you have an example of what your final output should look like? -- P.S. Please review: [mcve]

Comment: thanks for the quick response.yes i not used <arr:string>.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need some declaration of that namespace.

Like:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:arr="http://myarr.org">
```

Or:

```
<arr:string xmlns:arr="http://myarr.org">
    <xsl:value-of select="/Accounts/Account"/>
</arr:string>
```

Try to check: http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_namespaces.asp